# Very Difficult Enumeration Problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**Question**: Suppose I have $k$ numbers $0,..,k-1$ in circular arrangement, or equivalently the classes $\mod k$. Find the number of ways the numbers can be assigned to the sequence $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ with $2n<k$ such that:

- $x_i\ne 0,\forall i\in\{1,...,n\}$
- $x_i\ne\pm x_j, \forall i,j\in\{1,...,n\}$
- $x_i+x_j\ne 1,\forall i,j\in\{1,...,\ell\}$ where $\ell\leq n$

edit: every operation is in $\mathbb{Z}_k$ above, you can assume $k$ to be odd

I can do this without the last condition as I can clearly see it is equal to $(k-1)(k-3)...(k-2n+1)$ as each time I simply get to choose from the remaining elements of $\mathbb{Z}_k\backslash\{\pm a_1,...,\pm a_{i-1}\}$. Maybe this can take the form of placing the $x_i$ in $k$ boxes or something?

edit: I think I have an idea

- consider the numbers of $\mathbb{Z}_k$ ordered like so: $1,-1,2,-2,...,\frac{k-1}{2},-\frac{k-1}{2}$ as boxes
- for $x_1,..,x_{\ell}$ the conditions above are equivalent to placing every $x_i$ element in a box such that no two adjacent boxes both contain an element. This is equivalent to partitioning the elements of $1,-1,2,-2,...,-\frac{k-1}{2}$ with the $x_i$ such that no $x_i,x_j$ have only one element in between. This is just the number of solutions to $a_1+a_2+...+a_{\ell+1}=k-1$ with $a_1\geq 1, a_i\geq 2, i\in\{2,...,\ell\}, a_{\ell+1}\geq 0$ which is $\ell!\binom{k-2\ell}{\ell}=\frac{(k-2\ell)!}{(k-3\ell!)}$
- The rest of the $x_{\ell+1},...,x_n$ can be chosen from $k-2\ell-1$ as the example I mentioned giving $(k-2\ell)...(k-3\ell+1)(k-2\ell-1)(k-2\ell-3)...(k-2n+1)$

Comment: Should condition two read $x_i\neq \pm x_j$?  And in condition three, should $\ell$ be $n$?

Comment: Yes $x_i\ne\pm x_j$ and no we can have $\ell\ne n$, thank you for noticing

Comment: But $\ell$ is not specified anywhere, you only specified $k$ and $n$. Can we just take whichever $\ell$ we like?

Comment: yes $\ell$ is just a fixed number, the enumeration is with respect to $k,n,\ell$

Comment: Since $x_1,\cdots,x_k$ are all positive, I question the 3rd constraint.  Do you intend the stronger constraint that it is **not** the case that $x_i + x_j \equiv 1 \pmod{k}$?  Also, with respect to the 3rd constraint, does it also apply when $i = j$, or is the constraint only to be applied when $i \neq j$?

Comment: Re my previous comment, a similar question with respect to the second constraint.  Is the second constraint with respect to modulo arithmetic (mod $k$), or standard arithmetic?

Comment: Yes everything is $\mod k$